# Soundcloud Wordpress Plugin passing database value into Shortcode

Tags: wordpress, plugins, soundcloud, shortcode

I'm using the SoundCloud plugin for Wordpress. The shortcode format they recommend using is:
[soundcloud]http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood[/soundcloud]

I've also searched and found that this format can be used as well:
[soundcloud url="https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/25121853" params="auto_play=false&hide_related=false&visual=true" width="100%" height="450" iframe="true" /]

Basically my question is how would I pass a database value into the url section of this shortcode. I've used shortcodes for other plugins before which involve the use of key="xxx", but the Soundcloud shortcode seems to need the url="xxx" part.

I'm sorry if this is unclear, it's my first attempt at getting help on stackoverflow.

Many Thanks,

Paul

Comment: The plugin actually just creates suitable tags around your link, it doesnot actually saves your sound in wordpress. So you will have to  just save the url in your database and use the code in the shortcode.

Comment: Thanks Omer. Which code would I use in the shortcode to reference the database value?

Comment: do you have the url in the database?

Comment: yes, it's stored under a key I called soundcloudlink

Comment: Well if you want to do it from the wordpress post editor, you will first have to install "Allow PHP in Posts and Pages" plugin. Then in the editor do something like [php] echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'soundcloudlink', TRUE );[/php]

Comment: Thanks Omer, I've been working on it all morning and I think you just cracked it for me!!

Comment: You are welcome, i will add it as an answer then to help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it from the wordpress post editor, you will first have to install "Allow PHP in Posts and Pages" plugin. As you already have the value in your post_meta table, All you have to do in your editor is something like.

```
[php] echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'soundcloudlink', TRUE );[/php]
```

Replace $post_id with the id of your post.